# Maximizing $f(x,y) = (a + x)(b + y)$ under the constraint $d=x+y$, where $a$, $b$, $d$ are known.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization

> Find the maximum of the function $f(x,y) = (a + x)(b + y)$ under the constraint $d = x + y$, where $a$, $b$, $d$ are known.

It seems "obvious" to me that you'd want to split it between the two so that both sides of the product are as equal as possible but no idea how to prove the result.

Sorry I don't know what kind of math this is so I tagged a few.

Comment: Try $(a+x+b+y)^{2}=(a+x-b-y)^{2}+4(a+x)(b+y)$ and keep in mind that square of real numbers are non - negative

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I don't understand where that equation comes from or how it is relevant to this question

Comment: try to work on the algebra and you will see that the equation is true. You mentioned that $a,b,x+y$ are known variable, therefore You know what $(a+x+b+y)^{2}$ is. Look at the RHS, if You want to maximize $(a+x)(b+y)$, you need to minimize $(a+x-b-y)^{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not acquainted with the trick mentioned in the comment, I elaborate on this a bit.

You surely know the binomial formula

- $(u+v)^2 = u^2+2uv+v^2$

From this it follows
$$(u+v)^2-(u-v)^2 = 4uv \Rightarrow uv =\frac 14((u+v)^2-(u-v)^2)$$

Now, you plug into this formula

- $u= a+x$ and $v= b+y$

and use $d=x+y$. So, you get

$$(a+x)(b+y)=\frac 14((a+b+d)^2-(a-b-d+2x)^2)$$

Obviously, the square expression we subtract on the RHS has a minimal value of $0$.

So, the maximal value you are looking for is

$$\frac 14(a+b+d)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

It's labeled as pre-calculus problem so I'll solve it without calculus.

$f(x,y)=(a+x)(b+y)=(a+x)(b+d-x)=-x^2+(b+d-a)x+(ab+ad)=-(x-(b+d-a)/2)^2+(ab+ad+(b+d-a)^2/4)$

The maximum can be obtained at $x=(b+d-a)/2$ and the maximum value is $ab+ad+(b+d-a)^2/4$

Comment: What is the motivation behind these steps and how do you know what the maximum is?

Comment: It is easier to deal with one instead of two variables, so I use the constraint to remove one. The rest are standard completing the square procedure (https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html).

Comment: But why complete the square in the first place? What leads you to consider this / how are you extracting the maximum?

Comment: @user771284 look at the last equation. a known quantity subtracted by a square. remember a square is non negative